# Adjust spacing between main text and footnote in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, spacing, footnotes

How does one tweak (preferably on an individual slide basis, instead of applying to all slides) the spacing between the main text and the footnote in beamer slides.

For example, in the following slides, I've tried tweaking the `\skip\footins` but it doesn't seem to have much effect on Slide 1 where I'd like to have a bit more space between Item 11 and the footnote line/text

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{4pc plus 8pt}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme}
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{frame}{First Slide}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \item Item 3
            \item Item 4
            \item Item 5
            \item Item 6
            \item Item 7\footnote{Some footnote}
            \item Item 8
            \item Item 9
            \item Item 10
            \item Item 11
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Second Slide}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \item Item 3
            \item Item 4
            \item Item 5
            \item Item 6
            \item Item 7\footnote{Some footnote}
            \item Item 8
            \item Item 9 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to tweak some selected slides, you could just add a `\vspace`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{4pc plus 8pt}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme}
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{frame}%[t]
    \frametitle{First Slide}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \item Item 3
            \item Item 4
            \item Item 5
            \item Item 6
            \item Item 7\footnote{Some footnote}
            \item Item 8
            \item Item 9
            \item Item 10
            \item Item 11
        \end{itemize}
        \vspace*{5mm}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}%[t]
    \frametitle{Second Slide}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \item Item 3
            \item Item 4
            \item Item 5
            \item Item 6
            \item Item 7\footnote{Some footnote}
            \item Item 8
            \item Item 9 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

do you looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}   % use of the metropolis theme:
                        % it breaks standard placement
                        % of footnotes (at bottom of a frame)
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}% <---

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{ % <---
  \makebox[1em][l]{\insertfootnotemark}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}
    \footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont\insertfootnotetext
  \end{minipage}\vskip 0pt 
                            }% end of footnote template

\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First Slide}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
        \item Item 6
        \item Item 7\footnote{Some footnote}
        \item Item 8
        \item Item 9
        \item Item 10
        \item Item 11
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second Slide}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1\footnote{test}
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
        \item Item 6
        \item Item 7\footnote{Nunc sed pede. Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo,
                              vehicula eget, interdum id, facilisis et, nibh.}
        \item Item 8
        \item Item 9
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, something like this. Is it possible to selectively apply the spacing to some slides but not others? And how do I adjust the spacing between the main text and the footnote line, tried changing a few numbers in your footnote template above but didn't change the spacing

Comment: @Skyork, footnotes should be an exception in presentations ... consequently in `beamer` they are not supported as in document classes intended for articles or books. if you like to change footnote style, redefine its template before frame, where you like to apply new style. from aesthetic point of view and clarity of presentation i not recommend to do this. about new question in comment i recommend to ask them in new question, that more people see them and aster than can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Beamer, this distance is adjusted by `\skip\@mpfootins`, for example:

```
\makeatletter
\skip\@mpfootins0pt
\makeatother
```